# Bosonization on the lattice fermion - a rigorous mapping

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, research-level, lattice-model, bosonization

An inquiry: usually the bosonization is done on the field theory side. The mapping between the fermion operator to the boson operator is done for the **field theory operators**.

As far as we know for the bosonization on the lattice fermion, **do we know whether there is any exact result about the rigorous mapping: from the lattice fermions to a lattice boson?**

Any recommended approach or Ref on the rigorous "bosonization on the lattice fermion"?

ps. I have some fair understanding of uses of field theory Bosonization. Just wonder the lattice side procedure how well is it rigorous studied. Thank you!

Comment: by Ref searching, I can find, for example, [Lattice Bosonization](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9601060), [Bosonization on a lattice: The emergence of the higher harmonics](http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.51.4807), [Bosonization and the lattice Gross-Neveu model](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/9312028), etc. But here I simply wish to have experts to comment about this Bosonization on the lattice fermion and in a rigorous view.

Comment: perhaps the Jordan-Wigner transformation on the lattice is a hint to this question.